# Server frequently hangs, my client wants me to do X while the proper solution is Y

Tags: centos, centos6, debugging, lag, trust-relationship

This question is more on etiquette rather than an actual server issue.

2 servers owned by a client of mine frequently stop responding (Fast, then really sluggish as in it takes 1 minute to execute `ls`, then stop altogether). I propose that we bring it down for maintenance but he wants me to set up a script to reboot it every time it locks up. What's worse is that the servers monitor each other, and the reboot commands have a mandatory 60 second delay (shutdown, wait 60 seconds, then startup). The problem with this is that there is a very good chance both of them lock up within 60 seconds of each other. Both shutdown commands can be sent to each other and both servers shut down at the same time. No one will be able to send the startup command. Just a few moments ago, we had a 2-hour downtime because of this exact reason.

Now, my client wants me to "set a flag" so the shutdown commands don't get repeatedly sent. But, that doesn't eliminate the hang-at-the-same-time problem and the servers will still go down together eventually.

Rebooting the servers isn't a good solution at all IMHO. I've suggested we find the root cause and fix it. I've also suggested he use `watchdog` but he <s>denied it</s> put it on hold. I even gave up and said he should fire up a small dedicated server for monitoring but still he *wants* me to do it.

My dilemma right now is if I should **do what he asks** (reboot the server every time it hangs) or simply **log into his servers without permission and apply the needed fixes** to get it over with. We can't move forward at all because of this. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: You should investigate and fix the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do your best to research, explain the situation and the risks to your client. If he still wants you to do things his way, do it. He's the boss/customer, he should get what he wants. Even if it doesn't make sense. Alternatively you could quit or refuse to service that client if you are concerned this situation could damage your reputation or cause other serious problems for yourself.

I think many of us have been in similar, though not quite as bad situations.  Where customer/company decisions trickle down into our work and put us in this difficult position. Things like finances, policies, strategic business relationships, lack of education, power trips and others can all be problems. Having to fight to do the right thing sucks, but having to do the wrong thing when you know it's wrong sucks even more. People should be coming to you for your expert opinion. Just make sure you warned them, so when things go bad nobody will think it's your fault.